# ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException with new usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a small C# Application that uses a tooltip icon.

However, anytime I create a new usercontrol, I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException
'tbNotifyIcon' resource not found.
at MS.Internal.Helper.FindResourceHelper.DoTryCatchWhen(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args,  Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

tbNotifyIcon is an usercontrol that is in a resource directory. The code works fine, but the designer crashes every time on this error when I close the user control. In a new user control tbNotifyIcon is not used, yet I get the error in the designer. What could be wrong?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: So you're saying it works fine at runtime? Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved this issue, it was related to I suppose Caliburn executing some code that I had placed in a constructor. After removing my FindReference code to locate the UI element from the constructor this problem was gone.